# Data is getting over each other when setting my Base adapter with SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

I'm making a to do list application, i made a SQLite database and linked it with my app and everything seems to work pretty fine except for the data in the array, they get over each other while creating a new item, like when i set a first task (Study) and a second task (Research) it creates two different items each of them has the name (StudyResearch)... here is my code with the base adapter, cursor, and inflater.

```
 class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<ListItem> Items=new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> Items ) {
        this.Items=Items;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "tasks");
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return Items.get(position).Name;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return  position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        String[] cols = {"id", "name", "time", "date"};
        Cursor pointer = db.query("tasks", cols, null,null,null,null,null);
        String name = "";
        String time = "";
        String date = "";
        //String data = "";
        while (pointer.moveToNext()){
            name += pointer.getString(1);
            time += pointer.getString(2);
            date += pointer.getString(3);

            //data += pointer.getInt(0) + " - " +  pointer.getString(1) + " - " + pointer.getInt(2) +" - "  + pointer.getInt(3);

        }

        LayoutInflater linflater =getLayoutInflater();
        View view1=linflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);

        final CheckedTextView tvTasks =(CheckedTextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.tvTasks);
        CheckedTextView tvDesc =(CheckedTextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
        tvTasks.setText(name);
        tvDesc.setText(date + "(" + time + ")");   //date + "(" + time + ")"


        tvTasks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvTasks.toggle();
            }
        });

        return view1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that your are traversing all of the data in the cursor combined with += is concatenating the data retrieved.
Rather what you want to do is **position** to the appropriate row in the cursor and get the data just from that row *(not that I'd recommend this way as a CursorAdapter is better suited)*.

So instead of  :-

```
    while (pointer.moveToNext()){
        name += pointer.getString(1);
        time += pointer.getString(2);
        date += pointer.getString(3);
    }
```

You could use :-

```
     if (pointer.moveToPosition(i)){
        name = pointer.getString(1);
        time = pointer.getString(2);
        date = pointer.getString(3);
    }
```

This does assume that the the order in which the pointer cursor and the source array were built is identical.

Comment: That did solve the problem immediately, thank you so much I've been looking into this for about 4 hours now :D

Comment: @HadyElHawary my plesaure.

Comment: @HadyElHawary PS you should really have `pointer.Close()` after the above (after and outside the if clause/construct) so the Cursor is always closed, so as to avoid too many being open.